# how i creat log file in unix?

Tags: unix, bash, log-files

i write bash file to do a certain event .... now i want to creat log file to record date of executing bash file and result of execute it "exit code" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "[$(date +%c)] Process exited with result code: $?" >> /var/log/something.log
```

Feel free to change `+%c` with something else appropriate. See the `date(1)` man page for details.